# loop on a select input ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to make a select input on all my users in ruby on rails, that almost works but the thing is that the don't get the username of my user but i render somethings like this : `#<User:0x007f8cc1024d60>`

I created 3 users in my console, I can see them while i'm on rails console
I got this in my controller :

```
  def new
    @bug = Bug.new
    @users = User.all
  end
```

Also my params

```
def bug_params
    params.require(:bug).permit(:owner, :title, :description)
  end
```

And in my html :

```
<%= form_with model: @bug do |form| %>
<%= form.select :owner, @users %>

<%= form.text_field :title, placeholder: "title" %>
<%= form.text_area :description, placeholder: "description" %>
<%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Could someone explain me what's wrong ?

Comment: Have you defined a `to_s` method in the `User` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your `select` form helper, you return only a collection of `User` instances.

As specified in the [documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/select), you need to collect what attribute of `User` you want to pass as option value and option display.
For example:

```
<%= form.select :owner, @users.collect {|u| [ u.name, u.id ] } %>

#=> output
#  <select name="bug[owner]">
#    <option value="1">John</option>
#    <option value="2">Joe</option>
#  </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`collection_select`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.2/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select) to create a select from a collection of records.

```
<%= form_with model: @bug do |form| %>
  <%= form.collection_select(:owner, @users, :id, :name) %>
  <%= form.text_field :title, placeholder: "title" %>
  <%= form.text_area :description, placeholder: "description" %>
  <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```